# mysql script in shell using variables

Tags: mysql, shell

I would like to use mysql syntax in my shell scripts with variables,
what am I using wrong ?

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql <MyBlaBlaDB> -e "select * from table where something = &1"
```

and I'm trying to run it as ./test.sh

Comment: I don't see any variable usage in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way,

```
#!/bin/bash

something="anyting"
mysql -u [username] -p[password] [datbase name] -e "select * from table where something = $something"
```